# Thunderbird: Respond to an already-processed event

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird 115.3.0 with several email accounts configured. Today, I received an invitation to a work meeting. When viewing the message, a purple bar appears near the top with options to Accept, Tentatively Accept, or Decline the invitation. I clicked accept.

After selecting the calendar for the event, Thunderbird produces a popup dialog asking the user to select the email address from which the response to the invitation should be sent. This time, after clicking accept, I stumbled through that dialog and selected the wrong email address.

[image]

I'm not certain why this dialog is necessary, but it appears every time I respond to an event invitation, in any account, without exception. My email address is indeed present in the guest list.

Now, when viewing the message, the bar at the top indicates that the message "contains an event that has already been processed", and does not provide response buttons.

Normally this wouldn't be an issue, but I need to respond to the invitation again, and select a different sending email address this time. How can I accomplish this?

Viewing my calendar through Thunderbird, the event has appeared as expected. If I open it from there, I can click the Accept/Tentative/Decline buttons once again, but they do not provide the opportunity to select a new sending email address.

How can I resend the event response from the correct address? Any answers or suggestions are welcome.